# Probability that the network is connected in an unstructured p2p network

Tags: probability, graph-theory, network

Suppose that three nodes form an unstructured p2p network (a network where each node has a list of neighbors node, in which there are addresses of c live neighbors) and each selects to cache the IP address of one of the other two nodes. What is the probability that the network is connected?

Comment: welcome to [MATHEMATICS](http://math.stackexchange.com/). Please tell us your works on problem to help you more better.

Comment: Yes, of course. according to my thinking, assuming that the node P has c neighbors, the probability that one of them is exactly the node Q (ie, the next node) is c/N-1, in this case c / 2. But for the entire network how can I extend the problem? I'm thinking for example of using Bayes, but I don't know if it's the right way.

Comment: I think we need to more precisely define the model. Does each node pick one of the others uniformly at random? In this case, we need either A->B->C->A or A->C->B->A, which are two possibilities out of the 2*2*2=6 possibilities (because each node has two choices), so the chance is 1/3.

Comment: I think so, I think that each node pick one of the others uniformly at random (is not specified any distribution or something else). Thank you so much !